# как получить переменную в PHP из AJAX запроса?

Tags: php, javascript

как получить переменную в PHP из AJAX запроса?
Пробовал $_REQUEST и $_POST не помогает

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <select size="" name="select" id="select">
  <option value="1">first</option>
  <option value="2">second</option>
  <option value="3">third</option>
  <option value="4">forth</option>
  <option value="5">fifth</option>
  <option value="6">sixth</option>
 </select>

 <div id="output"></div>
 <script>
 
 window.onload=function(){


  var sel=document.getElementById('select');
  if(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value==0){console.log(sel[0])}
  for(var i=0;i<sel.length;i++){

   sel.onchange=function(){
    var idishnic = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    //alert(idishnic)

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST","query.php");
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onload = function(){
     document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
    xhr.send(idishnic);

   }
  }
 }
  
  
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php

$servername = '*****';
$username = "****";
$password = '***';
$dbname = "****";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


$select = $_REQUEST['idishnic'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id = $select ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0){
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  echo "<br> video: ". $row['video'];
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Если у вас есть дополнения - __отредактируйте вопрос__, никогда не вставляйте код в комментарии.

Comment: Вы шлете просто какое-то число, откуда бы в массиве POST взяться ключу `idishnik`?

Comment: Ну вот вы же сами пишите `xhr.open("POST","query.php");`. Ну так и ищите в `$_POST` данные. Что выводит `var_dump($_POST);` ?

Comment: @ArchDemon так как заставить заработать? Должно по выбранному option из value зарисоваться значение в переменную и передаваться в PHP переменяю. Почему значение не передаётся в PHP переменную?

Comment: Потому что массив POST это массив ключ-значение. Вы передали значение, а ключ кто передавать будет? Пушкин? Так он умер.

Comment: Все, понял, спасибо